# scrollViewDidEndDecelerating always returns 1 when first called in ios7

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview, gesture

Hi I'm building my first app and have run into a problem.

I'm building a page to review videos. The page opens with the correct selected video and has scrolling actions to allow swiping forward and back through the array.

The scrolling action triggered by the following code always results in the first right swipe setting the index to 1 ( and left to 0 ) which results in the selected video no longer being adjacent to the correct videos.

I'm wondering if someone can help me out with a suggestion for how to make the following code make the first swipe result in the index staying in order. I've been trying all sorts of things all day with no luck. I have a lot to learn.

I'm trying to somehow get the first swipe to acknowledge the self.currentVideoIndex, does this seem right?

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
if ( scrollView == videoCollectionView )
{
    int index = videoCollectionView.contentOffset.x / videoCollectionView.frame.size.width; // original   int index = video CollectionView.contentOffset.x / movieCollectionView.frame.size.width;

    NSLog(@"index %i",index);

    [self setVideoIndex:index];
}
```

}

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: OK this code works, the problem was caused by not initiating the offset in the viewDidLoad. added      [videoCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(videoCollectionView.frame.size.width*self.currentVideoIndex, 0)];   which now initiates the offset

Answer (score 0):

OK this code works, the problem was caused by not initiating the offset in the viewDidLoad. added
    [movieCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(movieCollectionView.frame.size.width*self.currentVideoIndex, 0)];

which now initiates the offset